# Failed to load dx.jar in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android programming and I want to set set up my environment for android programming but have encountered this error in the way i keep getting this error when i run the project i tried cleaning the project many times but the problem doesn't solve and my basic sdk tools are also installed [image: Image included]

I am linking a image of my sdk manager along with this my android sdk manager :

[image: Please tell if something is missing in it that i need]

THANK YOU

Comment: You should use Android Studio not eclipse

Comment: but the problem is of android sdk not of eclipse